# Does ServletRegistrationBean use different classloader for each registered child WebApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, classloader

I have situation where I'm registering two child web application context into Spring parent web application context, by using `ServletRegistrationBean`, providing different instance of `DispatcherServlet` to each of them. And each of them is served under different context path.

Main problem here is that each `ServletRegistrationBean` has one bean which is using same third-part library, which is using `getInstance()` from *static* member. And expected behavior is to have one instance of that class per `ServletRegistrationBean`. So when `getInstance()` is called from second `ServletRegistrationBean`, new instance will be provided, not the one created in first `ServletRegistrationBean`.

Question is, does beans in each of two different `ServletRegistrationBean` will be created and internally will use different instance of classloader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Spring documentation:

> Please be aware that Spring's concept of a singleton bean is quite
>   different from the Singleton pattern as defined in the seminal Gang of
>   Four (GoF) patterns book. The GoF Singleton hard codes the scope of an
>   object such that one and only one instance of a particular class will
>   ever be created per ClassLoader. The scope of the Spring singleton is
>   best described as per container and per bean.

So, I believe, two different ServletRegistrationBean will be created. If you need a true singleton you need to do it the old fashioned way - private constructor, a static getInstance method and code to handle serialization if you implement serializable.
More here:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch04s04.html#beans-factory-scopes-singleton

Comment: Actually I have two different beans using class from same library, and that class is singleton as is in GoF. If each bean under different ServletRegistrationBean uses different classloader, I will get different singleton class from that library. This is desired situation. Just rechecking is it expected behavior from Spring.

Comment: Yes, it is expected behavior.